# Reading XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

a portion of an xml file:

```
 <publisher>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <id>943</id>
 </publisher>
```

c#:

```
string publisher = n.SelectSingleNode(".//publisher").InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(publisher + "\n");
```

The c# program reads text off an xml file. The problem I'm having is that the `publisher` will have a string value of `ABC943`. Is there a way to just return the string value `ABC`?

Okay thanks for the answer. I have another question!!! Let's say:

```
 <publisher>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <id>943</id>
  </publisher>
  <publisher>
    <name>DEF</name>
    <id>3453</id>
  </publisher>
```

C# code:

`string publisher = n.SelectSingleNode(".//publisher//name").InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(publisher + "\n");`

Now, this will only read ABC. What do I do to make it read ABC, DEF? The number of publishers may vary..

Comment: iterate through the publisher nodes and print names like James Hay suggested.

Comment: so, i need to create a foreach loop for publisher? publisher is the new root.

Answer (score 3):

```
publisher = n.SelectSingleNode(".//publisher//name").InnerText;
Console.WriteLine(publisher + "\n");
```

For multiple nodes use [XmlNode.SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
XmlNodeList xnl = n.SelectNodes(".//publisher//name");

foreach(XmlNode xn in xnl)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xn.InnerText + "\n");
}
```

Comment: XmlNodeList pub = root.SelectNodes(".//publisher");

foreach (XmlNode xn in pub)
       {
       publisher = publisher+xn .SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText + ", ";
       }

Comment: But you don't need to execute multiple XPath. Just get all the names elements and get the innertext. For XPath queries check the syntax on w3schools site.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
publisher = n.SelectSingleNode("//publisher/name/text()");
Console.WriteLine(publisher + "\n");
```

Also, you don't require the . at the start of the xpath. "//" takes you too the root of the document.

In response to your second question, if you only want the first "name" then use this xpath:

```
//publisher/name[1]/text()
```